# Securing ASPNET Core Web API for calls from Azure Function

Tags: azure-functions, azure-ad-msal, microsoft.identity.web

We have an exisiting ASP.NET Core Web Api in Azure that has endpoints that support Azure AD and Azure AD secured users

I want to create a new Azure Function with a Timed trigger that will call this same Web Api. The call will obviously not be in the context of a user but in the context of the Function App.

The AF is AzureFunctionsVersion "v3" with a TargetFramework of "netcoreapp3.1"

I have added an App Role to the App registration for the existing Web API

[image: App Role exposed from Web Api]

I have then requested access to the that API from the Azure Functions "Api Permissions" blade in Azure Portal

[image: API's App Role granted]

I am only running this Azure Function locally as yet so here are the values from local.settings.json. I've removed the real values

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
    "AzureAd:Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "AzureAd:Domain": "ourdomain.co.uk",
    "AzureAd:TenantId": "aaaaaaaa-92eb-430b-b902-aaaaaaaaaaaa",
    "AzureAd:ClientId": "aaaaaaaa-bd17-4e69-bdf6-aaaaaaaaaaaa",
    "AzureAd:Audience": "https://ourdomain.co.uk/appid,
    "AzureAd:ClientSecret": "THESECRET",
    "PatientApi:BaseAddress": "https://myapi.com/api/",
    "PatientApi:Scopes": "https://my-api-appiduri/.default"
  },
}
```

I then try an get a token for the Azure Function  by calling GetAccessTokenForAppAsync

```
 var accessToken = await this.tokenAcquisition.GetAccessTokenForAppAsync(this.patientScope);
            
 this.httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
 this.httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
```

When I call GetAccessTokenForAppAsync I get the following Exception

> Microsoft.Identity.Client.MsalServiceException: 'A configuration issue
> is preventing authentication - check the error message from the server
> for details. You can modify the configuration in the application
> registration portal. See https://aka.ms/msal-net-invalid-client for
> details.  Original exception: AADSTS7000215: Invalid client secret
> provided. Ensure the secret being sent in the request is the client
> secret value, not the client secret ID, for a secret added to app
> '{CLIENTID_FOR_AZUREFUNCTION}'.

Is this AzureAd config and calling GetAccessTokenForAppAsync the right approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR**

Whilst I had correctly configured the AzureAd values I must at some point have chosen to "Manage User Secrets" in the VS  IDE. That had created a different ClientSecret and that was overriding the correct value in local.settings.json.

Thanks to this GitHub issue and comment from the MSAL team, https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/issues/379#issuecomment-666526566

Answer (score 0):

While using the `GetAccessTokenForAppAsync` you have only passed the scope.

But  `GetAccessTokenForAppAsync` require multiple parameters such as tenant, authenticationscheme , tokenAcquisitionOptions, etc .

That might be the reason for the `A configuration issue is preventing authentication` error stated by you .

Refer the following [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identity.web.itokenacquisition.getaccesstokenforappasync?view=azure-dotnet) on `GetAccessTokenForAppAsync` and the detail description on the parameters you need to pass.

You can also refer the following [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/api/latest/aad/app-aad-token) to get Azure AD tokens by using the Microsoft Authentication Library.

Comment: I'll try that but I have called GetAccessTokenForAppAsync elsewhere in our architecture within an ASP.NET Core Web APi in exactly that way with no problems

Comment: Tried explicitly passing the TenantId and the auth scheme but that made no difference. I don't see anything helpful on TokenAcqusitionOptions.